# How do I hard-code variables in a dynamically created function in python?

Tags: python

I have the following python3 code

```
class Test:
    pos = [0,0]
    actions = []
    def bar(self, target):
        for i in target:
            def _():
                print(i,end="")
            self.actions.append(_)
foo = Test()
foo.bar("abcd")
for i in foo.actions:
    i()
```

Which is meant to output:
`abcd`

but instead it outputs:
`dddd`

I'm pretty sure the function is using the value of i when executing (the last value i had) and not i's value the function _ is declared, which is what I want.

Comment: Each iteration of the loop doesn't create a new scope. So all the functions share the same `i` variable.

Comment: There is a second problem, the variable is at the class level  you need to initialize `actions` in `__init__` or it will be done at the class level, which is shared for all `Test`, not for `foo` which is a single instance of `Test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution to this is to store the value as a default parameter value, like this:

```py
class Test:
    pos = [0,0]
    actions = []
    def bar(self, target):
        for i in target:
            def _(i=i):  # This is the only changed line
                print(i,end="")
            self.actions.append(_)
foo = Test()
foo.bar("abcd")
for i in foo.actions:
    i()

>>> abcd
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the fastest solution

Answer (score 2):

Let's output some things:

```py
class Test:
    pos = [0, 0]
    actions = []

    def bar(self, target):
        for i in target:
            print(f"i={i} id={id(i)}")

            def _():
                print(f"_i={i} _id={id(i)}")
                print(i, end="")

            self.actions.append(_)
```

Output:

```
i=a id=2590411675120
i=b id=2590411458416
i=c id=2590411377456
i=d id=2590411377200
_i=d _id=2590411377200
d_i=d _id=2590411377200
d_i=d _id=2590411377200
d_i=d _id=2590411377200
```

See, the `i` in `def _` overrides every time for loop iterates and eventually last value is what you get.

How to solve this? Pass `i` as an argument:

```py
from functools import partial


class Test:
    pos = [0, 0]
    actions = []

    def bar(self, target):
        for i in target:
            print(f"i={i} id={id(i)}")

            def _(i):
                print(f"_i={i} _id={id(i)}")
                print(i, end="")

            self.actions.append(partial(_, i))
```

Output:

```
i=a id=2618064721392
i=b id=2618064504688
i=c id=2618064423728
i=d id=2618064423472
_i=a _id=2618064721392
a_i=b _id=2618064504688
b_i=c _id=2618064423728
```

Let's remove print statements now:

```py
from functools import partial


class Test:
    pos = [0, 0]
    actions = []

    def bar(self, target):
        for i in target:

            def _(i):
                print(i, end="")

            self.actions.append(partial(_, i))


foo = Test()
foo.bar("abcd")

for i in foo.actions:
    i()

# Output: abcd
```

Comment: actually i think you are bit mistaken, because the function `_` isn't overridden and you can check this by inspecting the ids of the functions references in the `actions` list  .  saving reference of the function prevents the default behavior form happening thus a new function is defined (not sure why this happen)

Answer (score 0):

the reason why you are getting the last value of `i` is that the function print takes reference to `i` and not literal value of it and since it's in a loop you will get the last value `i` had. a workaround to this problem would be as [Mandera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73341569/12594882) said  to set function default parameter and this actually works because the value of `i` is stored in the function's attribute `__defaults__`, which is responsible of storing default parameters values.
So the final code would be :

```py
class Test:
    pos = [0,0]
    actions = []
    def bar(self, target):
        for i in target:
            def foo(p=i):print(p,end="") 
            self.actions.append(foo)

           
if __name__=="__main__":
    foo = Test()
    foo.bar("abcd")
    
    for i in foo.actions:
      i()
```

**Note** 
the function `foo` isn't overridden